# Loading and using models in opencart

Tags: codeigniter, opencart

Open cart is based on CodeIgniter as I understand but in CodeIgniter to load and use the model you do something like this

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');

$this->Model_name->function();
```

In OpenCart you do something like this

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts()
```

How does this work and where does the "model_catalog_product" come from?

It seems like they have 0 developer documentation besides their forums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCart's loader class [seems to be inspired](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=5204&start=0) by CodeIgniter, but it's not based on it.  You can look into the source of OpenCart, see file `system/engine/loader.php` (Line 39).

```
public function model($model) {
    $file  = DIR_APPLICATION . 'model/' . $model . '.php';
    $class = 'Model' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $model);                      

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);

        // Right here. Replaces slash by underscore.
        $this->registry->set('model_' . str_replace('/', '_', $model), new $class($this->registry));
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not load model ' . $model . '!');
        exit();                 
    }
}
```

You can clearly see that it replaces slashes with underscores and append `'model_'` before the model's name.  That's why you end up with `model_catalog_product`.

Comment: Great explanation! So it's not based on CodeIgniter just follows some of it's conventions. What's the best way for me to master OpenCart if the documentation is gone?!

Comment: Good question.  You could try to ask [the community](http://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=109) if they have any recent developer guide or tutorials.  There's always the code itself, that won't lie and is always up-to-date. (Might be a pain...)

Comment: Doesn't seem like I can create a new thread in "support" section. I did make a thread a few days ago in the "coding" section about documentation and have 0 replies.

Answer (score 2):

The `model_catalog_product` comes from the path folder structure and file name within the model folder, so `model_catalog_product` is the `model/catalog/product.php` file, with the extension removed and the slashes changed to underscores. Also, notice that the model class name also refers to a similar structure, which is `ModelCatalogProduct`. As for the documentation, there was *some* documentation for developers, but just checked briefly and it appears that it's been removed for whatever reason. I learn't from lots of trial and error unfortunately, as have most developers using it

Comment: That's not the documentation I was referring to - There was actually a whole documentation system on the main opencart.com site however you are correct that that does provide some much needed basic information